# How to apply a filter to multiple vector layers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, query, filter

I am trying to apply an attribute filter to multiple layers in QGIS at once. The filter is to be applied to .osm data brought in through PostGIS to QGIS.

I have tried selecting multiple layers -> right-click --> filter but it only applies it to the last layer I selected of the group. I want to be able to apply a filter through a query like `"osm_user" = 'donlaser'` to multiple layers at once, rather than having to repeat the process many times.

Is there a standard way to do this within QGIS that I am missing? Is there a plugin that would provide this functionality?

A Python-based solution would also be useful for me.

Comment: Are you Ok if I give you a (short) solution with Python?

Comment: Yes. I would be open to trying a Python solution.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is how I'd do it with PyQGIS:

In your QGIS ToC, turn off those layers that you want to keep untouched, i.e., leave visible only the layers you want to set the filter to.

Now open a QGIS Python console and paste this code:

```
layers = iface.mapCanvas().layers()
for layer in layers:
    layer.setSubsetString('"osm_user" = \'donlaser\'')
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: That worked, but it really isn't a final solution for me.   How would I apply it to every layer in a specific layer group?

Comment: If I get you right, just make that specific group visible and all the other groups invisible. Otherwise, please edit your question and please make that clearer.

Comment: yeah you are right, I could achieve that just by toggling group layer visibility, thanks so much!

Comment: That's great! You're welcome.

Comment: The backslash is a escape, it helps the interpreter to deal with the subsequent single quote in a different way, so that it is acknowledged as a single quote included into the expression. If you omit the backslash, the single quote finishes the expression and is not included there, resulting into: "osm_user" =      I guess python would raise a syntax error or, the expression will not be applied successfully.