# Applying filter expression on custom made plugin in QGIS 2.18?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am developing a plug-in for QGIS 2.18 on Python but unable to find anywhere that how can I apply a filter expression on a layer in the .py file of plug-in?

For example, `"fclass" = 'bank'  AND "name" = 'xyz bank'`

```
    def run(self):
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""
    layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
    # layer_list = []
    # for layer in layers:
    #     layer_list.append(layer.name())

    layer = layer_pois2
    layer.setSubsetString('"fclass" = "bank"  AND "name" = "meezan bank"')
```

Comment: Don't forget to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134255/how-to-apply-a-filter-to-multiple-vector-layers-in-qgis?rq=1